# ReactJs requires a wrapper div which breaks the layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following React code:

```
render() {
    return (
      <NavItem dropdown toggleOnHover className='collapse-left'>

        <DropdownButton nav>
          <Icon bundle='fontello' glyph='bullhorn' />
          {this.getBadge()}
        </DropdownButton>
        <Menu alignRight ref='bullhorn-menu' id='notifications-menu' className='double-width' alwaysInactive>
          <MenuItem header>
            <Entity entity='Notifications' />
          </MenuItem>

          {this.state.notifications.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <Notification notification={item} key={index} />
            )
          })}

          <MenuItem noHover>
            <Grid collapse style={{marginBottom: -10}}>
              <Row>
                <Col xs={12} collapseLeft collapseRight>
                  <Button block className='notification-footer-btn left-btn'>MARK ALL READ</Button>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Grid>
          </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </NavItem>
    )
  }
```

The code above doesn't work, because it throws:

```
react-with-addons.js:9729 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
```

However, when I surround the map() statement with a div, it works, but that breaks the layout.

The `Notification` component just returns something like this:

```
<MenuItem href='/'>
        <Grid>
          <Row>
            <Col xs={2} className='avatar-container' collapseRight>
              <div><img src='/imgs/avatars/avatar22.png' width='40' height='40' alt='sarah_patchett' /></div>
              <div className='text-center'>
                <BLabel bsStyle='info'>NEW</BLabel>
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col xs={10} className='notification-container' collapseLeft collapseRight>
              <div className='time'>
                <strong className='fg-darkgray50'><Icon bundle='fontello' glyph='chat-5'/><em><Entity entity='notificationsTimeFirst' /></em></strong>
              </div>
              <div className='message-header'>
                <strong className='fg-darkgreen45'>Sarah Patchett sent you a private message</strong>
              </div>
              <div className='message-details fg-text'>
                <span>{"Hey Anna! Sorry for delayed response. I've just finished reading the mail you sent couple of days ago..."}</span>
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Grid>
      </MenuItem>
```

Can someone tell me how to just loop over my array and render the Notification component, without the surrounding div?

Comment: Hi. Where's the `toUpperCase()` being called?

Comment: In Reacts own code.

Comment: I think you can't, react uses that DIV internally and cannot be removed

Comment: Thats stupid. I breaks the layout very badly. I also tried using the Menu component as wrapper but that doesn't work too.

Comment: More info here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127

It's not stupid, is just how JSX works,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Currently it is not possible to return multiple components like that](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127), so you need to wrap them in something.

Why don't you just change the style of the container so that it doesn't break the layout?

For example:

```
<div style={{ display: "inline" }}>
    {this.state.notifications.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <Notification notification={item} key={index} />
        )
    })}
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
let menuItems = [
    <MenuItem header key="header">
        <Entity entity='Notifications' />
    </MenuItem>
].concat(notifications);

return <Menu>
    { menuItems }
</Menu>;
```

Now the contents of the menu is an array, so every item needs a key.

Comment: because it still breaks. The Menu component needs MenuItem children to work. It looks like it renders a list with list items.

Comment: compilation fails on { ...notifications }

Comment: @Phillipp the spread operator is an ES2015 feature, so if you're targeting an older version then it won't be supported. I've added another suggestion.

Comment: @TomFenech I use ES6 classes so it should work. However, the last version worked like a charm. You are awesome!

Comment: @Phillipp I think the solution with the spread operator was wrong anyway, so I removed it. Glad it's working for you.